# Attribute Error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, attributeerror

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html= urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
soup= BeautifulSoup(html.read())
print(soup.find("img",{"src":"../img/gifts/img1.jpg"
}).parent.previous_sibling.get_text())
```

The above code works fine but not the one below.It gives an attribute error as stated above. Can anyone tell me the reason?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen       
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html= urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
soup= BeautifulSoup(html.read())
price =soup.find("img",{"src=":"../img/gifts/img1.jpg"
}).parent.previous_sibling.get_text()
print(price)
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: both yield $15.00

Comment: Wish I could say the same.. I have tried restarting and everything but same error. I will try and look into the code once more. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare the first and the second version, you'll notice that:

*First:* `soup.find("img",{"src":"../img/gifts/img1.jpg"}).parent.previous_sibling.get_text()`

- Note: `"src"`

*Second:* `soup.find("img","src=":"../img/gifts/img1.jpg"}).parent.previous_sibling.get_text()`

- Note: `"src="`

The second code returns `Attribute Error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'` because it couldn't find `src=="../img/gifts/img1.jpg"` in the provided soup.

So, if you remove the `=` in the second version, it should work.

---

Btw, you should explicitly which parser you want to use, otherwise `bs4` will return the following warning:

> UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best
>   available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a
>   problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different
>   virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave
>   differently.
>
> To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:
>
> BeautifulSoup([your markup])
>
> to this:
>
> BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

So, as stated in the warning message, you just have to change `soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read())` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')`, for example.

Comment: I am very new to all this. Thanks a lot!!