# Getting NoneType error in Jupyter but not in online console

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter

I'm trying to get data from https://stooq.pl with BeautifulSoup. I work with jupyter where after running my code I get *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'*, but when I run it on online console it works fine.
My code looks like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

params_list = ['cdr','asb','hbg','ida','oat']
for param in params_list:
    p = {"s": param}
    response = requests.get("https://stooq.pl/q/",params=p)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    value = soup.find(text="Kurs").parent.find("span")
    print(value.text)
```

Erros is displayed in line: value = soup.....
Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm unable to detect your issue !

Comment: https://serving.photos.photobox.com/362089800e5d035d44a42a990956d4dfcae7b364f450e243e831f921e0f7ad3ec342d8ba.jpg

Comment: Hmm, i got your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478806/attribute-errornonetype-object-has-no-attribute-parent

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη before posting I saw this topic and it couldnt solve my problem. I dont know why it works on other platform than jupyter

Comment: does `response` have the html you expect in jupyter?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yeah, because I tried it manually and it works

Comment: i tried in my juypter instance and indeed it worked ok